# Label n days before and after a specific date for groups

Tags: python, pandas, date, grouping, timedelta

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   ID                Date  Main_Date
0   1 2015-04-02 12:00:00      False
1   1 2015-05-02 15:00:00       True
2   1 2015-02-15 00:00:00      False
3   2 2015-03-06 00:00:00       True
4   2 2016-11-20 00:00:00      False
5   3 2015-04-10 00:00:00       True
6   3 2016-07-28 00:00:00      False
7   3 2018-05-21 00:00:00      False
```

I want to add a column with `True/False` values if a `Date` is in the range 1 month before or after the `Main_Date` for every `'ID'` group , so my expected output is:

```
   ID                Date  Main_Date  Within_Range
0   1 2015-04-02 12:00:00      False          True
1   1 2015-05-02 15:00:00       True          True
2   1 2015-02-15 00:00:00      False         False
3   2 2015-03-06 00:00:00       True          True
4   2 2016-11-20 00:00:00      False         False
5   3 2015-04-10 00:00:00       True          True
6   3 2016-07-28 00:00:00      False         False
7   3 2018-05-21 00:00:00      False         False
```

I wrote a function for this:

```
def check_if_within_range(date):
        # Select the `Main_Date` for the `ID` group 
        main_date = df.loc[df['Main_Date'] == True, 'Date'].iloc[0] #This line causes the problem
        # Specify the range of dates as all dates 1 month before and after the `Main_Date`            
        month_start = main_date - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        month_end = main_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        month = pd.date_range(month_start, month_end)
        # Check if `Date` is within range            
        return (date > month_start) & (date <= month_end)

df['Within_Range'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:check_if_within_range(x))
print(df)
```

But I could not figure out how to select the `Main_Date` for every `ID` group. As it is now the first line in the function takes the first `Main_Date`.

Also the way I add the days results in `2015-04-02 15:00:00` being the `month_start` for the `Main_Date` `2015-05-02 15:00:00` so that `2015-04-02 12:00:00` is considered to be out of range. So I would like to specify the `month_start` in such a way that it covers the whole day.

This is the false output I get with the function I wrote:

```
   ID                Date  Main_Date  Within_Range
0   1 2015-04-02 12:00:00      False         False
1   1 2015-05-02 15:00:00       True          True
2   1 2015-02-15 00:00:00      False         False
3   2 2015-03-06 00:00:00       True         False
4   2 2016-11-20 00:00:00      False         False
5   3 2015-04-10 00:00:00       True          True
6   3 2016-07-28 00:00:00      False         False
7   3 2018-05-21 00:00:00      False         False
```

I also do not know if this is a good way to do it or if it could be done much easier as I am new to Python, so I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    "Date": pd.to_datetime([
        "2015-04-02 12:00:00", "2015-05-02 15:00:00", "2015-02-15 00:00:00", 
        "2015-03-06 00:00:00", "2016-11-20 00:00:00", "2015-04-10 00:00:00", 
        "2016-07-28 00:00:00", "2018-05-21 00:00:00"
    ]),
    "Main_Date": [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def check_if_within_range(group):
    main_date = group.loc[group['Main_Date'] == True, 'Date'].iloc[0]
    main_date = main_date.normalize()
    month_start = main_date - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
    month_end = main_date + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
    group['Within_Range'] = (group['Date'] >= month_start) & (group['Date'] <= month_end)
    return group

df = df.groupby('ID').apply(check_if_within_range)

print(df)
```

[image]